# How to insert a coloring domain plot into another coloring domain plot?

Tags: plotting, complex

This is my code. But I don't know how I could insert two different graphics on inside another.

```
    Restart[]
f[z_] := z
paint[z_] := 
color = Hue[Rescale[ArcTan[-x, -y], {-Pi, Pi}]];
shade = Mod[Log[2, Abs[x + I y]], 1];
Darker[color, shade/4]];
gr1 = ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, paint[f[x + y I]]],
Frame -> True, MaxRecursion -> 1, PlotPoints -> 300,
PlotRangePadding -> 0, Axes -> False, Mesh -> False,
PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImageSize -> 400];
gr2 = ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, -0.1, 0.1}, {y, -0.1, 0.1}, 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, paint[f[x + y I]]],
   Frame -> True, MaxRecursion -> 1, PlotPoints -> 300,
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, Axes -> False, Mesh -> False,
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImageSize -> 400];
Graphics[{First[gr1], Inset[gr2, {15, -.5}, Automatic, Scaled[.4]]}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-1, 1}}, AbsoluteOptions[gr1]]
```

Comment: if other people solve your problem , please set it as ANSWER.

Answer (score 3):

```
Graphics[{First[gr1], 
  Inset[gr2, Scaled[{1, .5}], {Right, Center}, Scaled[.4]]}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-1, 1}}, AbsoluteOptions[gr1]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this will help a lot.!!!!!!!!